# Passing structure by reference and assign string

Tags: c++, function, pointers, structure

Here is a simple program where I am trying to pass a structure to a function by reference and a string. The function is supposed to detect the length of the string and assign it a member of the structure. Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

struct stringy   // structure definition
{
    char *str;
    int ct;
};

void set(stringy &beany, const char *testing);   // function definition

int main()
{
    stringy beany;
    char testing[] = "Reality isn't what it used to be.";
    set(beany, testing);   // function call
    return 0;
}

void set(stringy &beany, const char *testing)   // function prototype
{
    int i=0;
    while (*(testing+i) != '\0')    // this loop counts the number of characters
    {
        i++;
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    beany.str = new char[i];    // dynamic storage allocation
    std::cout << strlen(beany.str);   // printing the length of the string
}
```

For some reason the output of the last line in the function set() is 47 while the value of "i" is 33. The last 15 bytes are filled with garbage value. I want that the length of beany.str should be equal to the length of *testing.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate memory for `beany.str` but you don't *initialize* that memory. The contents of the allocated memory, without any initialization, is *indeterminate* (and in practice will be seemingly random).

Also don't forget that old C-style strings needs to be terminated by the special `'\0'` character (or functions like `strlen` will not work).

Both of these problems, using uninitialized memory and forgetting the terminator, will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> beany.str = new char[i];    // dynamic storage allocation
> std::cout << strlen(beany.str);   // printing the length of the string
> ```

`strlen` looks for the terminating null character `'\0'`. There is no guaranteed one in `beany.str`, because you assign it the result of `new char[i]`, which does not zero-initialize the elements. It allocates space for `i` characters that are **not initialized to zero**.

Even if they were, `strlen` would return 0, because it would immediately find `'\0'` at the first position. If you don't somehow remember `i` yourself, the size information will be lost.

Look at the output of the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char *str = new char[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << str[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

The behaviour is undefined. What you will *probably* see are some seemingly random characters.

If you want zero-initialization, use `new char[i]()`.

But still, `strlen` will be 0:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = new char[100]();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << str[i] << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << strlen(str) << "\n";
}
```

You should just get rid of array-new and array-delete. Use `std::string`.